# NSArray valueForKey ObjectAtIndex

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have an NSArray that i want a single value of.

```
_membersArray = [_detailItem valueForKey:@"members"];
```

When i use this code:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[[_membersArray valueForKey:@"name"] count ]);
```

i get: 1

When i use this one:

```
    NSLog(@"%@", [_membersArray valueForKey:@"name"] );
```

i get

```
{(
    "Name Lastname"
)}
```

But i need only "Name lastname"

And when i use:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[_membersArray valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

i get:

```
[__NSSetI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bf5caf0
2014-03-13 12:35:39.261 Givem[2454:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSetI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bf5caf0'
```

i guess this is a easy one but i have a codeblock. Thanks for helping me out

Comment: show your full json..

Comment: This is what i get when i log it: 2014-03-13 12:27:54.104 Givem[2409:60b] {(
    "Name Lastname"
)}

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: I means, post your full json, not your log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then try this..

```
[[[_membersArray valueForKey:@"name"] allObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked indeed. Will accept when possible

Answer (score 0):

Look at exception ... It says ...

```
[__NSSetI objectAtIndex:] ...
```

... it means, that you're trying to send `objectAtIndex:` message to `NSSet`, not `NSArray`. And `NSSet` doesn't have `objectAtIndex:` method.